# Android passing a JSON Object from activity into a listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-activity

I have a really simple question. can somebody give me an example of how to PASS an JSON Object from an ACTIVITY INTO a LISTVIEW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject obj = obtainJSONObject();
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(obj);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

or after getting data, you can use below code:

```
mAdapter.setJSONAdapter(obj);

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public CustomAdapter(JSONObject obj) {...}
    public void setJSONAdapter(JSONObject obj) {
        .....
        notifyDataSetChange();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so do I still need to start a new intent?  in order to pass it?

Answer (score 0):

You will use an adapater.

Read more about Android ListAdapters here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Comment: do you have an example you can show me